# Application crashes while scrolling my custom gridView

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

[image]

I want my grid view to be like the grid view in the picture, so that the cells in the most right column are only buttons and the rest cells contain Imageview and textview

This is my custom adapter

```
public class AllCategoriesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Recipe>{

private ArrayList<Recipe> RecipesInfo;
private Context con;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public AllCategoriesAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Recipe> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    RecipesInfo         = objects;
    con                 = context;
    imageLoader         = new ImageLoader(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RecipeItemHolder recipeHolder;
    View view ;


    recipeHolder = new RecipeItemHolder(); 
    int type     = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null ) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) con).getLayoutInflater();
        if ( type == 3 )
        {
            view                = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_button_row, parent , false);

        }
        else
        {
            view                = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_recipe_list_row, parent, false);

        }
        view.setTag(recipeHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        view = convertView;
        recipeHolder = (RecipeItemHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Recipe rItem = (Recipe) this.RecipesInfo.get(position);

    if (  type == 3 )
    {
        recipeHolder.button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btCategoryButton);
        recipeHolder.button.setText(rItem.getCategoryName());
    }
    else
    {
        recipeHolder.RecipeTxt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRecipeCell);
        recipeHolder.img        = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRecipeInCategory);
        recipeHolder.RecipeTxt1.setText(rItem.getName());
        /*Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Drawable top = new BitmapDrawable(con.getResources(),b);
        recipeHolder.RecipeTxt1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, top, null, null);*/
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(String.valueOf(rItem.getImageId()), recipeHolder.img);
    }


    return view;
}



public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (position%4);
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}
public void setArray (ArrayList<Recipe> obj)
{
    RecipesInfo = obj;
}

private static class RecipeItemHolder {
    TextView RecipeTxt1;
    Button   button;
    ImageView img;
}
```

}

but the view crashes when scrolling

```
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at    android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6355)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4883)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3087)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3361)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4342)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-30 13:19:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9593):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 13:19:11.040: E/Trace(9624): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `getCount()` to your `adapter`

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return RecipesInfo.size();
}
enter code here
```

**EDIT :**

You don't need to use `getItemViewType` et `getViewTypeCount` because you return the view based in the `type = getItemViewType(position);`

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond. Your answer before the edit helps to make the code run correctly without crashing. "Making getViewTypeCount returns RecipesInfo.size()" .. But when I scroll the position of buttons change

Comment: @NayraAhmed getViewTypeCount return 2 is correct keep it and add getCount()

Comment: If the scroll problem still check out http://lalit3686.blogspot.com/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: The gridView still crashes on scrolling after adding getCount();

Comment: with the same logcat ?

Comment: yes with the same logcat `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2`

Comment: are you sure that you add `getCount(){return RecipesInfo.size();
}`

Comment: yes, I am sure `@Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 2;
 }
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return RecipesInfo.size();
 }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65903/discussion-between-abdellah-and-nayra-ahmed).